# Spring WS AbstractJDomPayloadEndpoint deprecated warning

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

For my java soap webservice, Spring-ws says AbstractJDomPayloadEndpoint deprecated and I get warning in my code, even debugger does not hit any point in the class, how can I change it? do I need to change a lot of things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AbstractJDomPayloadEndpoint`, like all `PayloadEndpoint` implementations, [is deprecated in Spring-WS 2.x](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/AbstractJDomPayloadEndpoint.html), in favour of annotation-style endpoint classes.

However, the old endpoint classes still work fine. If your service isn't working, this has nothing to do with the deprecation.

Comment: tnx how can I change it to annotation-style endpoint classes, does that need big changes in my code?

Comment: @XDeveloper: Yes, it'd be a rewrite, pretty much.  Read the Spring-WS 2.x manual to see what's involved.